# Auto edit NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

What code could be used to edit parts of an `NSString`, I want it to make it change "International" to "Intl." and remove the word "Airport" from the string.

Example: "Honolulu International Airport" would become "Honolulu Intl."

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation for NSString and attempt the changes you want. If you have problems ask for help then.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all occurances of the string "International" with "Intl." within your `NSString`:

```
NSString *newString = [initialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"International" withString:@"Intl."];
```

Also,

What could add even more functionality is an `NSMutableString`.  It carries over all of the functionality of an `NSString`, but adds mutability, meaning you can remove or replace parts of a string, or add more to it.  Here is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSMutableString`.  In addition, you can Google more tutorials for it.